# How do I add labels to a Dundas Chart?

Tags: c#, .net, dundas

How to add labels to my graphs to indicate which series is what.

My clients don't want legends, they want the labels on the chart area. Possibly with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to set labels is when you bind your data to the chart.

Eg. for a piechart (may be different on other types):

`chart.Series["seriesName"].Points.DataBind(MyDataList, "xFieldPropertyName", "yFieldPropertyName", "Label=xFieldPropertyName{p2},LegendText=legendPropertyName");`

Comment: Thanks! I had already figured it out though. Not too many people with Dundas experience here.